# ASP.NET MVC4 multiple file upload not work from mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile, file-upload

I have the following code, you can enter the site from url: http://nirh1989-001-site1.itempurl.com/

When i open the url from desktop, i can upload multiple files at once, but when i open the url from my mobile browser i can only upload 1 file at a time.

Why?

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p></p>
                <label for="file">Upload Photo:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="gallery">
        @if (ViewBag.Images != null)
        {
            var imgID = 0;
            foreach (var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
            {
                imgID++;
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="@Url.Content(image)">
                    <img id="@imgID" src="@Url.Content(image)" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" />
                </a>
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("/Content/Photos")).Select(f => "/Content/Photos/" + Path.GetFileName(f));
            return View();
        }

        //POST: Home
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in file)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                    string imgPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Photos/");

                    item.SaveAs(imgPath + fileName);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("/Content/Photos")).Select(f => "/Content/Photos/" + Path.GetFileName(f));
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding the `multiple` attribute to the input file control.

Comment: the input file already have the `multiple` attribute (otherwise i couldn't upload multiple files even from desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was nothing wrong with my code... the problem was the mobile, i tried to upload multiple files from a folder in the phone that for some reason not allowed multiple choices... tried to upload from gallery and everything is ok